# Get Cell Values from Variant to Range

Tags: vba, excel

How do I get back the cell values to the range from a Variant array? I get run time error 9 subscript out of range error.
cellPosition contains values (B9, C10, F6...)

```
For i = LBound(cellPositions) To UBound(cellPositions)
    save_fix_general_data(i) = ActualWBK.Worksheets(1).Range(cellPositions(i)).Value
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: Impossible to tell with the 4 lines of code posted, but a good guess would be that `save_fix_general_data` isn't the same size as `cellPositions`.

Comment: Why do you need the +1 incrementation?

Comment: @Comintern , save_fix_general_data will be the same size as the cellPositions . The problem is might be syntax issue I guess. The goal is to fill save_fix_general_data with values from the actual opened workbook where the range reference is the cellPosition

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually set the dimensions of `save_fix_general_data`?  If you're getting a subscript error, the immediate problem is a subscript error.  If you had a syntax issue, you'd get a compiler error.

Comment: You are incrementing the iterator of a for loop **inside** the loop. This means that i will not have every value between lbound and ubound but also that the last value of i will exceed the array bounds and throw the error you see.

Comment: @matt_black - No, actually the loop will simply exit.  It's basically the same thing as `For i = LBound(cellPositions) To UBound(cellPositions) Step 2`.

Comment: @Comintern On reflection you might be right, but I wouldn't guarantee it as playing with loop counters inside the loop is often unpredictable in consequence and always a bad thing to do.

Comment: @Comintern Dim save_fix_general_data() As Variant here is where I declare the variant, but I assign values in the cycle

Comment: Do you ever `ReDim` it? I.e. `ReDim save_fix_general_data(LBound(cellPositions) To UBound(cellPositions))`?

Comment: @Comintern `ReDim save_fix_gen(0)
For i = LBound(cellPositions) To UBound(cellPositions)
    save_fix_gen(i) = ActualWBK.Worksheets("Bid Leveling Template").Evaluate(arr(cellPositions(i)).Value)
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve save_fix_gen(i)
Next`

Comment: Can you [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39470261/edit) to include all of the code relevant to the loop?

Comment: @Comintern I edited my comment, any tips? Can I assign empty cells to an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning values to variant crashes, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473994/assigning-values-to-variant-crashes-why)

Answer (score 0):

this one is working by its own, you would probably get the meaning. It prints the values in A1, A2, A3 and A4 of the first sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RangerHarmiony()

    Dim arr(3)          As String
    Dim l_counter       As Long

    arr(0) = "A1"
    arr(1) = "A2"
    arr(2) = "A3"
    arr(3) = "A4"

    For l_counter = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print Range(arr(l_counter)).Value
    Next

End Sub
```

It should be sufficient to do what you want to :)