# Assigning values to variant crashes, why?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this cute code here, which goes through a tons of files with selecting folder and has to collect stuff to a new sheet. In this part I would like to store the header data to an array, because it is static and has to be appended to each row. The header information comes from the cellPosition array, which contains cell values like B2. Inside the for cycle I get error on save_fix_gen(i)= crashes some how at the 2nd element (i=2) and I can't figure it out why. Any help would be appreciated with a big plus!

fyi

```
(
    Dim save_fix_gen() As Variant, cellPositions() As Variant, i As Integer
    cellPositions() = get_general 'this comes from a function and
)
    Do While myFile <> ""

    Set ActualWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile)

    ReDim save_fix_gen(0)
    ActualWorkBook.Worksheets("SheetName").Activate
    For i = LBound(cellPositions) To UBound(cellPositions)
        save_fix_gen(i) = CStr(Evaluate(cellPositions(i)))
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve save_fix_gen(i)
    Next

    Loop
```

Comment: Have you checked the contents of cellPositions in the locals window, make sure there is nothing in there that shouldn't be?  Also, why not dimension your save_fix_fen based on cellPositions?

Answer (score 0):

This worked, thank you. Simply set the array to the max size of the input.

```
ReDim save_fix_gen(UBound(cellPositions))
ActualWBK.Worksheets("Bid Leveling Template").Activate
For i = LBound(cellPositions) To UBound(cellPositions)
    save_fix_gen(i) = CStr(Evaluate(cellPositions(i)))
    i = i + 1
    'ReDim Preserve save_fix_gen(i)
Next
```